# Дерево папок в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как при событии Button.Click открыть дерево папок для выбора файла, который надо открыть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать объект класса OpenFileDialog:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
```

Затем:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Или создать объект класса FolderBrowserDialog и:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: А откуда возьмутся `openFileDialog1` (и возможно `2`, `3` и `4`), автор вопроса должен догадаться сам?

Comment: @VladD,не беспокойтесь,по ссылкам умею переходить))

Comment: @david_I, обновил ответ

Comment: @Александр спасибо

Comment: @david_I, не за что, сразу надо было написать так)

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужен `OpenFileDialog`:

- WPF: [Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx)
- WinForms: [System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)

Можно пользоваться любым, диалог одинаковый. `:-)`

Comment: спасибо за помощь!